# How to write a Quickcheck property for ANSI escaped coded string parser?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, quickcheck

Please consider the following piece of code:

```hs
-- Represents a parsing result of an ANSI coded string.
data Slice = Slice
  { text :: String,
    color :: Color
  }

newtype Color = Color
  { string :: String
  }

-- A function that receives a string with ANSI esacpe codes and returns a list of slices.
categorize:: String -> [Slice]
categorize codedString = ...
```

Now, I wish to write a quickcheck property for the `categorize` function.
I have something like this in mind:

```hs
-- A quickcheck generator for ANSI coded strings.
ansiEscapeStrings :: Gen String
ansiEscapeStrings = ...

main =
  verboseCheck $
    forAll
      ansiEscapeStrings
      (\codedString -> categorize codedString == WHAT_GOES_HERE)
```

My question is what goes instead of `WHAT_GOES_HERE`?

Thanks in advance.

#### UPDATE:

I already wrote properties for trivial things like length and empty list.

Comment: Since property-based testing uses random input, you can rarely predict what the exact output is going to be. Instead, you test *properties* of the function. What are the (planned) properties of `categorize`? Will it always return non-empty lists for non-empty input? Is there some relationship between the input size and the output list length? If so, write properties that verify that.

Comment: How can we know `WHAT_GOES_HERE` without knowing what property of `categorize` you're interested in testing? Also, since QuickCheck will evaluate your property with many different `codedString` values and `categorize` (presumably) is not just a trivial constant function, `== WHAT_GOES_HERE` is never going to be a reasonable test no matter what goes there. You don't want to test whether the output is equal to some known good value, you want to check some feature of the output.

Comment: Think of it like this. Imagine you haven't implemented `categorize` yet and someone else claims that they have, but you can't look at their code to tell if they've done it correctly. They are willing to randomly select input values, and then tell you what output is produced for each of those inputs. You need to examine the input/output pairs and say if their `categorize` function meets your specification. How would you tell? What observations and calculations would you check? If the answer to that question is something you can write down as a Haskell function, it makes a good property test.

Comment: (Or more likely a number of property tests; you *can* make a single property that tests whether a bunch of unrelated checks are true at the same time, but it's usually easier and better to split them up into multiple properties)

Comment: @MarkSeemann I already wrote properties for trivial things like length and empty list. Thank you. I will update my question accordingly asap.

Comment: @Ben `How can we know...` - Thank you very much. I've already updated my question.

Comment: @Ben `Think of it like this...` Good point. Understood. Thanks.

Comment: One approach is to generate the slices you want and encode them. Then demonstrate that your slice function recreates the same ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With QuickCheck, you should identify some rules you think should hold for all possible input/output pairs. It's rather difficult to do this if your concept of input is just "an arbitrary string to pass to the function" and the output is "the slices the function returns". At this level of abstraction, the only rule you can really write is "the function should produce the slices represented by the input string" - of course, you can't test that directly, because if you had a known-good conversion from input to output you'd just use that instead.

Instead, try some thinking at a more granular level. What are some ways you think this function should behave, *given certain properties of the input*? Here are some I can think of.

1. An empty input should produce an empty output.
2. The sum of the lengths of the `text` strings in an output should be no larger than the size of the input.
3. All the characters present in one of the `text` strings in an output should be present somewhere in the input.
4. If the input includes `n` color-change sequences, there should be `n` slices in the output. Or is it `n-1` slices? How are you planning to represent "text preceding any color-change sequences"? And what about if there are two color-change sequences in a row, with no text between them? Already, thinking in terms of properties to test has us finding important edge cases in the design.

These properties need varying levels of precision to test them. For (1), you don't even need QuickCheck: you can just unit-test the single, empty input. For (2) and (3), you could just pass an arbitrary string as input and compare the input and output data. But QuickCheck's arbitrary string generator likely won't produce many strings with meaningful ANSI escape sequences in them. So you will probably want to define `stringWithEscapeSequences :: Gen String` or something like that, to ensure your test inputs are interesting.

But (4) is more complicated. You *could* take an arbitrary string as input, scan it for escape sequences, and then compare that to the number of slices produced by `categorize`. But that requires including a lot of your function's implementation into the test, and a bug in your function could easily be mirrored by a bug in your test. A less fragile approach would be to write a data type for test cases, with a generator for that type, so that you know how many slices to expect from each test case ahead of time. Something like

```
data SliceCountTestCase = SliceCountTestCase 
  { numSlices :: Int, input :: String }
  deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Arbitrary SliceCountTestCase where
  arbitrary = do
    slices <- listOf slice
    pure $ SliceCountTestCase (length slices) (serialize =<< slices)
    where slice = (,) <$> color <*> listOf nonEscapeCharacter
          serialize (c, body) = escapeSequence c ++ body

prop_sliceCountMatches :: SliceCountTestCase -> Bool
prop_sliceCountMatches (SliceCountTestCase n s) = length (categorize s) == n
```

There are numerous spots in that example for you to fill in based on your domain knowledge: `color` and `nonEscapeCharacter` are all generators, while `escapeSequence` is an ordinary function of type `Color -> String`.

You could design another, similar property using many of the same combinators: given a list of slices as input, you should be able to encode it as a string, and `categorize` on that string should give you back the same result you started with

---

Here are some ideas for other properties you could test, without details on how to test them. Try to think small to come up with properties: you need something you can easily describe and verify.

1. A non-empty input should generate a non-empty list of slices. (Or should it? What if the only input is an escape sequence?)
2. The number of non-escape characters in the input should be the same as the sum of lenghts of the output slices
3. Suppose that a string `s` decodes to `p`. Choose an index `n` in `[0..length s`], and insert an arbitrary non-escape character `x` at position `n` in `s` yielding `s'`. Decoding `s'` should yield a list of slices much like `p`, except with a single extra `x` at the `n`th position.
4. Do something like (3), but insert an escape sequence instead and expect a new slice (Or maybe not, depending on how you're handling adjacent escape sequences).

In general, a fruitful avenue to explore is the theme in (3): Take an input and its corresponding output, perturb the input in some well-defined way, and observe that this changes the output in the expected way.